specific permissions to view own user dashboard?
I am stuck trying to figure out permissions to allow a user to see the data on their own user dashboard.
In Drupal, I have tried adding as many permissions as seemed possibly related:

access Contact Dashboard
access all custom data
profile create
profile edit
profile view
render templates
view all activities
view my contact
view my invoices
access CiviContribute
make online contributions
access CiviEvent
register for events
view event info
access CiviMail
access CiviMember  - View memberships
access CiviReport - View reports

But even with all these permissions, a logged in user who has paid for a membership can't see their own membership or contributions. The User Dashboard appears, but the membership and contrib data are missing.

However, if I then grant
all CiviCRM permissions and ACLs
Administer and use CiviCRM bypassing any other permission or ACL checks and enabling the creation of displays and forms that allow others to bypass checks.
THEN the user CAN see their own membership and contrib data.

Obviously, I don't want to give that permission to ordinary authenticated users.
But I've tried every other combination I can think of, and I can't get the data to appear.
Do I need to create an ACL just to allow people to view their own data? If so, are there more detailed instructions beyond the last section of https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/ ?
Is there another permission or option I've overlooked?
Thank you!

Agree documentation says that first one is all that is required. and lots of threads say the same. not sure why getting to /civicrm/user is proving a problem. when i am on a suitable site i will test. pls update your post with the drupal version

This looks like you are using the SK based User Dashboard extension? If so it might be worth disabling that and see if the info shows with the core dashboard in which case it can be checked in the extension.

RebeccaTregenna - THANK YOU! THAT WAS THE PROBLEM. I didn't realize the extension was different from the core dashboard. Disabling the extension fixed it. THANK YOU!  For future reference, petednz, Drupal version is 10.2.7 . THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!
